# Powershell intellisense when importing modules

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

At work we're developing a PowerShell solution using VSCode, the PowerShell extension and PSScriptAnalyzer. Our files are defined as `.psm1` files containging classes, and use `using module` to import other `.psm1` files using relative paths.

The problem is, that `using module` doesn't seem to support intellisense, i.e. is not statically analyzable by the PowerShell parser: `This can also be due the type not being known at parse time due to types imported by 'using' statements. PSScriptAnalyzer(TypeNotFound)`

I'm wondering if there is a way to import other modules using relative paths while still supporting intellisense.

Ideally this would happen in the `.psm1` files themselves to reduce setup time for new developers, but I'm ok with additional setup steps, i.e. adding them to `$env:PSModulePath`.

This is how the files are structured right now:

```
# ./BaseClass.psm1
class BaseClass {
  # ...
}

# ./SomeClass.psm1
using module .\BaseClass.psm1

class SomeClass : BaseClass {
  # ...
}
```